# Performance utility to send multiple requests from jar file

Tags: java, performance, stress-testing

I have created a jar file which will cause a request to go towards a API I am testing. It basically passes an object to an API. It is asynchronous call so nothing is returned in response

I need to stress test this API now so I was wondering instead of writing a script to call this jar in parallel is there any tools out there that I could use? Basically i could provide the tool with the command to run and it will write parallel requests to the API and I can monitor the process on server using jconsole etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for that. This tool is very flexible and provides enough functionality for most cases of stress testing.